# Error installing Octave on EC2 - Dependency of GraphicMagick

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, installation, octave, graphicsmagick

I am trying to install Octave on a AWS EC2 instance. When I execute

```
sudo yum install octave --enablerepo=epel
```

I get the following error:

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
944 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package octave.x86_64 6:3.4.3-2.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libGraphicsMagick++.so.12()(64bit) for package: 6:octave-3.4.3-2.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 6:octave-3.4.3-2.el6.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: libGraphicsMagick++.so.12()(64bit)
```

I´ve been trying to solve this problem installing GraphicsMagick manually but it didnt work. I also searched for the libGraphicsMagick++.so.12()(64bit) RPM but it leads to endless unsolved dependencies.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ever find a solution?